# Indoor positioning system in android

Tags: android, redpin

I would like to ask a question regarding redpin indoor positioning system on android. I read somewhere stackoverflow about redpin and visited their website. From there i followed their instructions on how to set up redpin on android, but i only get a red dot pointing on the top left corner of the map i uploaded. I would like to know if anyone has successfully gotten redpin to work for android and assist me in doing so?....or maybe can tell me what am I doing wrong. Sorry to ask, I am very new at this, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For what I could experiment, it doesn't really work at first, probably because of the lack of fingerprints or something like that. 
But when you have added quite a few locations, and try again to take locate, it starts pointing at a particular location.
For what I could notice, it works well on android 2.2, but there is some debug to do on 4.1 and 4.2 for it to work fine.
I hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

U would better read about INS (inertial navigation system), it is a navigation system that uses your phone sensors for calculation your position.

Comment: thank you...by the way, do you any recommendations of any open source projects done for INS?

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me as well, but which is not an error, and I guess it's just a failure of updating. Press the redpin image, if it can start the measurement, then it works well.